# Falha de login para o usuário "AUTORIDADE NT\IUSR"

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-service

To com uma aplicação WebService rodando no IIS, mas quanto tento consumir da esse erro:

> System.Exception: Login failed for user 'AUTORIDADE NT\IUSR'

Já tentei adicionar no banco de dados esse usuário, mas não consigo, da esse erro:

> O utilizador ou grupo 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR' do Windows NT não foi encontrado. Verifique o nome novamente.

Quando tento adicionar qualquer outro usuário:

[image]

Como resolvo isso? Estou usando Windows 8 e IIS 8

Comment: Já tentou adicionar esse usuário pela conta root do SQL server ? A "sa" ? Talvez você não esteja conseguindo por não ter a permissão na sua conta.

Comment: @ÉrikThiago ja tentei sim, estou logado com ela! E também executei o programa como administrador do sistema

Comment: Olha @Exception de acordo [esse link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324321/pt-br) o erro pode estar acontecendo porque o nome do computador pode estar errado. Já olhou se os nomes estão certos ? Talvez esse usuário exista mas em uma outra máquina.

Answer (score 3):

Vá na Application Pool do IIS que roda sua aplicação e troca o usuário para "NetworkService".

Application Pools -> Botão direito na escolhida -> Advanced Settings -> Identity

Daí no SqlServer Management Studio, adiciona o usuário "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

Comment: De onde vem o NT AUTHORITY\IUSR ?

Comment: não tem esse usuário no SQL SERVER. Tem o serviço de rede, mas quando adiciono, da o mesmo erro que está descrito na pergunta

Comment: Já alterou no IIS ?

Comment: @gmsantos alterei o que no IIS?

Comment: "Vá na Application Pool do IIS que roda sua aplicação e troca o usuário para "NetworkService"."